# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm probably just overlooking something very obvious, but i just do not get it to work, after trying several versions already.

I get a JSON File from a server, translated it into an array, to work with it inside PHP. So far everything works fine.

Now i want to call a Javascript function with the JSON as an parameter, but i always get an "Unexpected token"-Error, no matter if i put in the JSON or an PHP-array.

This is my code:

```
   <?php
    function tableHeader()
    {
        echo('<table class="mui-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Desc</th>
              <th>Settings</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>');
    }

    function addTableEntry($id, $name, $desc, $deviceArr)
    {
        echo('<tr>
                  <td>'.$id.'</td>
                  <td>'.$name.'</td>
                  <td>'.$desc.'</td>
                  <td><a href="#groups" onClick="activateGroupSettingsOverlay('.$id.',\''.$name.'\', \''.$desc.'\', '.json_encode($deviceArr).');">Gruppe verwalten</a></td>
                  <td><img src="../images/ic_delete_black_48dp_1x.png" class="delete" onclick="activateDeleteGroupOverlay(\''.$name.'\')" ></img></td>
                  </tr>');
    }

    function tableFooter()
    {
        echo ('
              </tbody>
            </table>
        ');
    }


    tableHeader(); 
    //addTableEntry(1,"Wohnzimmer","Lampe neben dem Bett");
    //addTableEntry(2,"Küche","Lampe in der Ecke");
    //addTableEntry(3,"Schlafzimmer","Die neue Lampe in der Küche");


    $jsonData = '[
                    {"id":1,"name":"Wohzimmer","beschreibung":"keine beschreibung","geraete":
                        [
                            {"id":2,"name":"PC","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":10,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Ich bin eine Beschreibung"}
                        ,   {"id":5,"name":"Beamer","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":20,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Beamer im Wohnzimmer"}
                        ]
                    }
                ,   {"id":2,"name":"Haus","beschreibung":"Schaltet das ganze Haus","geraete":
                        [
                            {"id":1,"name":"Waschmaschine","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":20,"status":0,"beschreibung":"Hallo"}
                        ,   {"id":2,"name":"PC","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":10,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Ich bin eine Beschreibung"}
                        ,   {"id":3,"name":"Anlage","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":10,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Hier koennte ihre werbung stehen"}
                        ,   {"id":4,"name":"Beamer","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":20,"status":0,"beschreibung":"Beamer im Schlafzimmer"}
                        ,   {"id":5,"name":"Beamer","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":20,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Beamer im Wohnzimmer"}

                        ]
                    }
                ]';

    $jsonDataParsed = json_decode($jsonData, true);
    foreach ($jsonDataParsed as $group) {
        addTableEntry($group['id'],$group['name'], $group['beschreibung'], $group['geraete']);
    }

    tableFooter();
?>
```

Edit:

```
<table class="mui-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Beschreibung</th>
          <th>Einstellungen</th>
          <th>Löschen</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody><tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Wohzimmer</td>
              <td>keine beschreibung</td>
              <td><a href="#groups" onClick="activateGroupSettingsOverlay(1,'Wohzimmer', 'keine beschreibung', [{"id":2,"name":"PC","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":10,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Ich bin eine Beschreibung"},{"id":5,"name":"Beamer","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":20,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Beamer im Wohnzimmer"}]);">Gruppe verwalten</a></td>
              <td><img src="../images/ic_delete_black_48dp_1x.png" class="delete" onclick="activateDeleteGroupOverlay('Wohzimmer')" ></img></td>
              </tr><tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Haus</td>
              <td>Schaltet das ganze Haus</td>
              <td><a href="#groups" onClick="activateGroupSettingsOverlay(2,'Haus', 'Schaltet das ganze Haus', [{"id":1,"name":"Waschmaschiene","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":20,"status":0,"beschreibung":"Hallo Mario"},{"id":2,"name":"PC","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":10,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Ich bin eine Beschreibung"},{"id":3,"name":"Anlage","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":10,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Hier koennte ihre werbung stehen"},{"id":4,"name":"Beamer","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":20,"status":0,"beschreibung":"Beamer im Schlafzimmer"},{"id":5,"name":"Beamer","bitIdent":"1","baudrate":20,"status":1,"beschreibung":"Beamer im Wohnzimmer"}]);">Gruppe verwalten</a></td>
              <td><img src="../images/ic_delete_black_48dp_1x.png" class="delete" onclick="activateDeleteGroupOverlay('Haus')" ></img></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: You should post the source of the generated html, it could also be any of the other variables that break the script.

Comment: I added the source of the generated html

Comment: The first double-quote in your json is ending your `onClick` definition.  Assign the json to a js variable first, and then pass that variable to the function.  Or escape the quotes, but the first option will probably be simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Patrick, it works now!